# Copy animated GIF to Clipboard on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, clipboard

Is it possible to copy animated GIF data to clipboard on Linux?

Under Windows, the file can be copied using Ctrl-C from Windows Explorer. But under Linux, file managers like Thunar copy the filename and browsers like Firefox or Chrome just copy the current frame as PNG.

It almost looks like the Linux clipboard doesn't support copying arbitrary data. Is that true or am I missing something?

Comment: This is how it works in Windows, too.

Comment: @gronostaj no, I can paste it into Firefox with a custom onPaste handler and can access the file contents from JavaScript.